# How works default calendar in activiti timer event?

Tags: alfresco, activiti, bpmn

I can't find in any doc which calendar activiti timer uses. Is it a business calendar (takes into account only weekdays) or a regular calendar?

I need to terminate process in 14 days by the regular calendar (2 weeks). So if I use this duration in timer event **P14D** will it trigger event in 14 days or in 14 weekdays????

Comment: Standard BPMN 2.0, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations

Answer (score 0):

I went through activivi calendars' source files and found out that it works with the regular calendar even though all that calendars named as "business" calendars.